# Model is null while submitting the form in partial view in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I am just trying to learn MVC and facing some issues.When I am submitting my partial view, I am getting null in Model **Blog** inside Create Method.

What I am doing wrong and what is the right approach?

**View(Index.cshtml)**

```
@model IEnumerable<Samples.Controllers.Blog>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Sample</th>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.URL
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Name
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

@Html.Partial("_CreateBlog", new Samples.Controllers.Blog())
```

**Partial View(_CreateBlog.cshtml)**

```
@model Samples.Controllers.Blog

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Sample",FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Blog</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.URL)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.URL)
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**SampleController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Samples.Controllers
{
    public class SampleController : Controller
    {
        List<Blog> lstBlogs;
        public SampleController() 
        {
            lstBlogs = new List<Blog> 
           {
               new  Blog{ Name="Domnic", URL=   "www.google.com"},
               new  Blog{ Name="Tom", URL=   "www.YAHOO.com"},
               new  Blog{ Name="Cat", URL=   "www.facebook.com"},
               new  Blog{ Name="Bob", URL=   "www.twitter.com"}
           };
        }
        // GET: Sample
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(lstBlogs);
        }
        public ActionResult IndexWithDynamicView()
        {
            return View(lstBlogs);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void Create(Blog blog)
        { 

        }
    }
    public class Blog
    {
        public string Name;
        public string URL;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class `Blog` only contains fields, not properties so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** their values. Change it add getters/setters

```
public class Blog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer relates to your question: [Is there a reason why the default modelbinder doesn't bind to fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559060/is-there-a-reason-why-the-default-modelbinder-doesnt-bind-to-fields)

Pay attention at [DefaultModelBinder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), [ModelBinderContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbindingcontext%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), [ModelMetadata](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/src/System.Web.Mvc/ModelMetadata.cs#17). This explains it all.